# Grails, left outer join

Tags: grails, groovy, left-join

I have two domain classes Users and Projects like following

```
Users{
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String emailAddress
    static hasMany = [projects:Projects]
}



class Projects {
    String projectName
    String description
    Users projectLead
    Date completionDate
    static belongsTo = Users
}
```

Here completionDate == null means the project has not yet been completed.

Now I want to send an email reminder to each user about their incomplete projects, How can write a query to retrieve incomplete projects per user?

I was thinking on following lines but am still not able to go ahead. In order to send an email I will need users emailid, all incomplete projects and names of them

```
def users = Users.list()
       for(user in users){
           user.projects.find{it.completionDate==null}
       }
```

Is it possible to use createCriteria in such a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
def usersAndIncompleteProjects = Users.withCriteria {
    projects {
        isNull( completionDate )
    }
}
```

That should just return you the Users with incomplete projects, and the `projects` property for each `User` will only contain the incomplete projects.  If you want the Users to have all of their projects loaded, I [believe you need to use an alias](http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/06/querying-by-association-redux.html)

---

***Testing...***

Given the User class:

```
package criteriatest

class User {
    String name

    static hasMany = [ projects: Project ]
}
```

And the Project class:

```
package criteriatest

class Project {
    String name
    Date completionDate

    static belongsTo = User

    static constraints = {
        completionDate( nullable:true )
    }
}
```

This integration test passes (hopefully the asserts explain it)

```
package criteriatest

import grails.test.*

class UserTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        User.withSession { session ->
            def tim = new User( name:'tim' )
            def dave = new User( name:'dave' )

            [ tim, dave ]*.save()

            def project1 = new Project( name:'project 1', completionDate:null )
            def project2 = new Project( name:'project 2', completionDate:new Date() )

            tim.addToProjects project1
            tim.addToProjects project2

            [ project1, project2 ]*.save()

            session.flush()
            session.clear()
        }
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    void testQuery() {
        def usersAndIncompleteProjects = User.withCriteria {
            projects {
                isNull 'completionDate'
            }
            order 'name', 'asc'
        }

        // We get two users back (users with no projects get returned as well)
        assert usersAndIncompleteProjects.size() == 2

        // First user (dave) has no projects
        assert usersAndIncompleteProjects[0].projects.size() == 0

        // Second user (tim) has one project (with a null completionDate)
        assert usersAndIncompleteProjects[1].projects.size() == 1

        // Check it's the right project
        assert usersAndIncompleteProjects[1].projects*.name == [ 'project 1' ]
    }
}
```

(this is the sql the criteria query executes in this instance):

```
select
    this_.id as id1_1_,
    this_.version as version1_1_,
    this_.name as name1_1_,
    projects3_.user_projects_id as user1_3_,
    projects_a1_.id as project2_3_,
    projects_a1_.id as id0_0_,
    projects_a1_.version as version0_0_,
    projects_a1_.completion_date as completion3_0_0_,
    projects_a1_.name as name0_0_ 
from
    user this_ 
left outer join
    user_project projects3_ 
        on this_.id=projects3_.user_projects_id 
left outer join
    project projects_a1_ 
        on projects3_.project_id=projects_a1_.id 
where
    (
        projects_a1_.completion_date is null
    ) 
order by
    this_.name asc
```

Comment: Just to confirm, after running this query if I were to do usersInstance.projects.each(){......} would it only iterate through projects with null completiondate?

Comment: I think that link illustrates pretty well why HQL is the way to go if you care about whether your join is inner or outer :)

Comment: That will select all users who have at least one incomplete project, I think.

Comment: Hey Tim, Thanks a lot the link explains a lot.

Comment: I've added a quick test to make sure it's still the same behaviour in Grails 1.3.7, and it seems to be...  Updating my answer with the code...

Comment: +1 for tests.  I forgot that's how associations in criterias work.  It can cause [some surprises](http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/04/associations-and-criteria-queries.html) though if you ever try to load the rest of the associations in the same session.

Comment: @ataylor Yeah...and in this situation, we **want** the suprise outcome, with only the uncompleted projects being returned ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this problem requires a left join, unless you want to include Projects with a null user.  Why not just select all projects with null completion dates and join against user?

In HQL, it would look something like this:

```
Projects.executeQuery('from Projects p join p.projectLead u where p.completionDate is null')
```

You can do similar in a criteria query:

```
Projects.withCriteria {
    isNull('completionDate')
    join('projectLead')
}
```

Comment: In this case I am not iterating through projects per users! What I  mean is I want to get all users and then retrieve incomplete projects for each. This way I can send one consolidated email per user.

Comment: If you call the HQL query, it'll return you a list of [project, user] pairs.  You can then call `results.groupBy{ it[1] }` to transform it into a map of users to [project, user] pairs, and iterate through that.

Comment: The query I provided gets it all in one query.  The straight-forward way of iterating over all Users with list and then selecting a list of incomplete projects is probably more obvious.  Unfortunately, it's a SQL anti-pattern ([n+1 selects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem)) that won't scale as well.